# Many years ago I made this image, but can't replicate

Tags: adobe-photoshop, filter

When I was a kid I used to screw around in Photoshop for fun, making desktop backgrounds for my PSP. I made one, which I've never, ever been able to replicate.

It's a *very* long shot, but I was wondering if anyone had any inkling as to how you may replicate it.

I never used to save my PSDs, and this is the highest resolution of the image that I have.

There's no 3D work involved.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Its just the Plastic Wrap Filter currently located in the Filter Gallery under Artistic Filters

[image]

Comment: I'll give it a go later, thanks!